# getParam retrieving null instead of user data

Tags: php, slim

I'm trying to post new user signup to the data using getParam, I used RestClient to test if value is retrieved or not turns out to be null every time:

this is the json data I put in the body, and I do add a content type header based on application/json:

```
{
  "email" : "test@test.com",
  "username" : "test",
  "password" : "123",
}
```

This is the code for posting user (note that var_dump($email) and die I used it just to check $email does contain a value or not, will be removed when it is fixed):

```
//add new user
$app->post('/user/add', function(Request $request, Response $response){
    $email = $request->getParam('email');
    $username = $request->getParam('username');
    $password = $request->getParam('password');

    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (email, username, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

    var_dump($email);
    die ("end");
    $conn = new Database();
    $conn = $conn->createConnection();

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('sss', $email, $username, $password);
    $check = $stmt->execute();
    $error = $stmt->error;

    if ($check){
        echo 'Added Successful';
    }
    if ($error != ''){
        echo $error;
    }

});
```

I did the same thing for posting appoinment by /calendar/add and it work prefectly, bot post method are the same but why post user is not getting the value?

Answer (score 0):

getParam() is only used for query parameters like: yoururl.com?param1=value1

You have to use

```
$body = $request->getParsedBody();
echo $body['email'];
```

instead

Comment: but I did the same thing in posting new appointment, for example:

    $subject = $request->getParam('subject');
    $location = $request->getParam('location');

but I still can get the data, do you know why ?

Comment: I had tried using getParsedBody but I still get NULL

Comment: I tried     $body = $request->getParsedBody();
    $email = $body['email']; and var_dump to test the data is being retrieve or not

Answer (score 0):

DZDomi's answer is not quite accurate because `getParam()` of `Request` class does call `getParsedBody()` method internally. It should work with query strings or data from POST body.

If you get NULL when sending POST request, make sure that you setup  client to use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`.

I do not know about RestClient, but if you use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/), you can define this information on Body tab on Postman UI.

[image: Postman UI]

Comment: How do I know my client is using those two paths u mention?

Comment: How do you add them? I suppose as `Content-Type` header?

Comment: Yes I add them as content-type